# Need to change engine oil type depend on kilo in honda hybrid

Tags: engine, honda, hybrid

Our Local car Mechanic suggest to change engine oil depend on kilo. For example, After My Honda Hybrid car has over kilo 100,000, they suggest to change another engine oil type such as `5W-30`.

But I read the Honda Hybrid Manual User Guide, it suggests only `0w-20` or `5W-20`(if `0W-20` is not available). There is no description for changing engine oil depend on kilo.

So Do I need to change engine Oil type based on kilo?

Comment: Do you have to top-up your oil between services?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to stick with the manufacturer's recommendations - they specify a particular oil "weight" (viscosity) for a reason, while there may be specific circumstances to deviate from this the fact that the car has hit a magic number of 100,000km certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: If the OP is truly worried about it, there are plenty of oil formulations out there which are for high mileage engines without changing the viscosity of the oil itself. Look for "High Mileage" on the packaging, like what is seen on this [Mobil1 example](https://mobiloil.com/~/media/amer/us/pvl/products/motor-oils/mobil-1-brand/mobil-1-high-mileage/products/mobil-1-high-mileage-oil.png).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 agreed!